# Does the Leaflet timeline require a copy of a feature for each time point

Tags: leaflet

My understanding of the Leaflet timeline (a Leaflet GeoJSON subclass) is that a GeoJSON feature is needed for each time point. Thus, if you were showing the same country with a different color over 100 years, you would need to have 100 features, including the same geometry in each, but with a different start/end time, and a style function pegging the color to the time.

Is that right? Or is there some more efficient way?

Comment: Are you asking about [this plugin](https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline)?

Comment: @SidneyGijzen yes

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct. But, and I haven't used this plugin, I also get the feeling that you can 'mimick' a feature by working with the [getInterval option](https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline#getinterval-function----optional). However, best way to test this is make a code sample with the data you've got and put it on jsfiddle. That would make it easier for people to help you.